# solr setup with wcs

Tags: java, solr, websphere, wcs

I am facing problem while running di-buildIndex and getting error in logs as:
in wc-dataimport-buildindex.log file at /install_commerce/logs/wc-dataimport-buildindex.log as

```
Apr 28, 2016 7:58:56 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper getLocalizedMessage(String, Object[])
FINER: ENTRY _INFO_DI_BUILDINDEX_EXIT_FAILURE_UNRECOVERABLE_ERROR [Ljava.lang.Object;@55815581
Apr 28, 2016 7:58:56 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper getLocalizedMessage(String, Object[])
FINER: RETURN Data import process was unsuccessful. An unrecoverable error has occurred.
Apr 28, 2016 7:58:56 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper printException
INFO: Data import process was unsuccessful. An unrecoverable error has occurred.
Throwable occurred: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /solr/MC_10001_CatalogEntry_Unstructured_en_US/dataimport was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:459)at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:199)        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:117)        at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.util.SolrUtil.makeDataImportNoCleanCommand(SolrUtil.java:481)        at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.DataImportProcessorMain.fullDataImport(DataImportProcessorMain.java:1773)        at om.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.DataImportProcessorMain.executeDIH(DataImportProcessorMain.java:927)        at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.DataImportProcessorMain.main(DataImportProcessorMain.java:424)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:267)
Apr 28, 2016 7:58:56 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper getLocalizedMessage(String, Object[])
FINER: ENTRY _INFO_DI_BUILDINDEX_DEBUG_WARNING [Ljava.lang.Object;@15d715d7
```

This buildIndex step is the 3rd step in configuration 1. setupSearchIndex 2. preprocess and both the steps ran successfully. However buildindex is failing. Can someone suggest where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Build index is failing because it is not able to hit the Solr url. You can check the following stuffs

1. Makes sure your server is started while running the script
2. Make sure the setupSearchIndex has created the Solr cores properly. You can check in WC_InsDir/Search folder if the cores are properly set up
3. In case if you have changed the port number 80 to something else, you need to change it in search configurations as well